# Unique icons next to each Wordpress menu item

Tags: php, functions, menus, filters

I have Wordpress menus that is seems are put together in the backend somehow. I used [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) to customize the wrap of the menu items slightly.

My issue is I have found no direct access to access the menu items, and add a custom field to them. They are all categories, and I want a specific icon for each category.

This is my code in the functions.php to customize the menu:

```
function custom_novice_menu($args) {
    $args['container'] = false;
        $args['container_id'] = 'my_primary_menu';
        $args['link_before'] = '<div class="topic-card"><div class="topic-circle"></div><h3>';
        $args['link_after'] = '</h3></div>';
    return $args;
}
```

Does anyone know a way I could add a unique icon to each menu item?

Answer (score 1):

In your theme folder, add this code to your functions file:

```
function menu_icon_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style( 'fontawesome', 'http:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_icon_stylesheet' );
```

Now you can add a class to each of your menu items. Click on the downwards arrow to view more options relating to that menu item. In the ‘CSS Classes’ field, type the following:

Like:

```
fa fa-lg fa-home
```

Here

```
"fa" is used for all items with a Font Awesome icon
"fa-lg" sets the size of the icon to large
"fa-home" relates to the specific icon you want to display.
```

Finally, add this style code in your stylesheet:

```
/* styling for menu icons */
.navigation-class ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
.fa::before {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 30px;
}
.navigation-class ul li.fa.fa-lg a {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Now your navigation menu is complete with icons!

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with an icon font, like FontAwesome, plus CSS, in your theme's style.css file (hopefully using a child theme). Each menu item is usually a list item in the HTML, and usually they each have a unique class and/or id, so you can use that to target each one. Add the `::before` selector to insert your icon before the list item, something like this:

```
li.class::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #43CC9E;
    content: "\f06c"; /* escaped unicode for the icon */
    float: left;
    width: 1.6em; /* icon width + space */
}
```

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/InSightGraphics/pen/Kzacd) I made, where you can play with the HTML & CSS using FontAwesome to place icons before list items this way.

[This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-font-awesome-with-wordpress/) tells you how to get FontAwesome into your WordPress site, and a lot more info about how to use it. There are, of course, other icon fonts, and the principles are the same.

On the [FontAwesome.io](http://fontawesome.io) website you can see each icon and get the unicode for each.